# Cannot install Genymotion 2.0.1 under Ubuntu: [[: not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, genymotion

```
sudo sh genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin
genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin: 100: genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin: [[: not found
genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin: 106: genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin: [[: not found
-e 
-e Aborting.
```

I have this problem on version 1.*, yesterday on 2.0 and today on 2.0.1 on Lubuntu 13.10 x32. I already writed to developers, but if in Google I can't find anything about this problem - it's affect only me? Maybe something not good at my side?

If I open this .bin file in Sublime Text 2 I have this code (from line 97 to 111):

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_ask_user() {
    local ans=a
    while [[ ! "$ans" =~ ^[YyNn]$ ]]
    do
        echo -ne "$1"
        read ans
    done

    [[ "$ans" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && return 0

    # if $ans == No
    return 1
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run

```
sudo bash genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin
```

or

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin && sudo ./genymotion-2.0.1_x86.bin
```

Andrei.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the problem is solved by Andrei B's answer, but I would like share a script that automatize all steps needed for install genymotion on linux. 
You can find the script [here](https://github.com/giordano91/genymotion_installer).

Maybe this can help some other users in the future.